# Accessing Flask parameter outside called function

Tags: python, flask

Without passing `user_name` to `other_function` as a param, how would I be able to access `user_name`?

```
@app.route('/profile/<user_name>/')
def profile(user_name):
    other_function()
    # do more stuff

def other_function():
    print request.args
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach the view arguments via [`request.view_args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Request.view_args), which is a dictionary:

```
def other_function():
    print request.view_args['user_name']
```